# Fortran runtime warning: Extension: $ descriptor

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using a very old Fortran 77 code from third party (also very bugged). I have compiled with

```
FFLAGS=-O0 -Wall -g -fbacktrace -pedantic -Wextra
```

I am getting the warning in the title at runtime:

```
At line <number> of file <namefile>.f (unit=6, file='stdout')
Fortran runtime warning: Extension: $ descriptor
```

I would like to figure out what that means.

Comment: Old Fortran codes are very likely to give **many** warnings, especially with `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`. They are very likely to contain both a) non-standard extensions, b) features which are now obsolete or even deleted. I don't think these options are very useful for old codes.

Answer (score 4):

You should always show the code line number in the error or warning message, to which the line points.

The role of `$` in

```
write(*,'(a$)') "string"
```

is to avoid going to the next line after printing "string" on the screen.

However, the descriptor is non-standard and therefore you are warned about this by the compiler.

The standard way is to use non-advancing input/output:

```
write(*,'(a)', advance="no") "string"
```