# gfortran error: unexpected element '\' in format string at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a project written in VS2010 with Intel Visual Fortran. I have a dump subroutine to write a 2D matrix into file:

```
subroutine Dump2D(Name,Nx,Ny,Res)
    implicit none
    integer i,j,Nx,Ny
    real(8) :: Res(Nx,Ny)
    character(len=30) name,Filename
    logical alive
    write(filename,*) trim(Name),".dat"
    Write(*,*) "Saving ",trim(Name)," Please wait..."
    open (10,file=filename)
    do i=1,Ny
           Write(10,FMt="(D21.13\)")   (Res(j,i),j=1,Nx)
           Write(10,*)  
    end do
    close(10)
    Write(*,*) "Save ",trim(Name),"Complete!"  
    return
end subroutine Dump2D
```

It is ok to compile and run. But when I compile in emacs using gfortran it gives me the error:

I think it's because the gfortran doesn't recognize `\` in a format for a write command. How do I fix this problem?

```
                Write(10,FMt="(D21.13\)") (Res(j,i),j=1,Nx)
                                   1
Error: Unexpected element '\' in format string at (1)
```

Comment: Backslash editing, as a Intel non-standard extension, isn't supported by gfortran.  That's not a very useful answer, though, so perhaps you could explain how you want gfortran to format the output.  That way there could be a more helpful answer.

Comment: @francescalus So what I want to formate the output is simple. To dump the 2d matrix into file in the form of : the first column of matrix written into first row of the file, the second column of matrix written into the second row of the file and so on.

Comment: What do you want to use to separate matrix elements in a line in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edit descriptor `\` relates to *backslash* editing.  This is a non-standard extension [provided by the Intel compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/692294) (and perhaps others).  It is not supported by gfortran.

Such backslash editing is intended to affect carriage control.  Much as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833518) such an effect can be handled with the (standard) non-advancing output.<sup>1</sup>

As you simply want to output each column of a matrix to a record/line you needn't bother with this effort.<sup>2</sup>  Instead (as you'll see in many other questions):

```
do i=1,Ny
   write(10,fmt="(*(D21.13))") Res(:,i)
end do
```

There are also other approaches which a more general search will find.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Intel compiler treats `\` and `$` in the same way.

<sup>2</sup> There are subtle aspects of `\`, but I'll assume you don't care about those.

Comment: I used your way to dump the file. But when I examin the file with origin8. It gives the error: `.dat does not seem to consist of columns of ASCII data`. It did not happen when I using the  ` \ `. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @vampCJ Have you tried looking at it using a text editor?

Comment: @SteveES Yes I looked into it, and it looks fine to me. but the origin wont read it.

Comment: @vampCJ Have you looked at it setting it to display all characters in the text editor (like spaces and line endings) for a file that works and a file that doesn't?

Comment: @SteveES I see whats wrong there. I accidently added a line: `Write(10,*)` which cause the error. It just works fine now.

Comment: Yes, @vampCJ, that `write(10,*)` is needed to advance the output after the non-advancing output for each column.  As the answer here uses advancing output there's no need to compensate.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (although francescalus answer is better in your case) would be to build a format string that contains the number of elements to include in your row. One way of doing this is to use the following to build the format string (which uses an explicit space character to separate elements within a line in the file):

```
WRITE(fmtString, '(A,I0,A)') '(', Nx, '(D21.13,:,1X))'    *
```

Then use the format string variable in your WRITE statement as so:

```
do i=1,Ny
   Write(10,FMt=fmtString)   (Res(j,i),j=1,Nx)
end do
```

This approach can also be very useful if you want to use something other than spaces to separate elements (e.g. commas or semicolons).

*As that's a little difficult to read, I will provide an example. For Nx = 3, this would be equivalent to:

```
fmtString = '(3(D21.13,:,1X))'
```

Which is 2 numbers formatted using D21.13, each followed by a space, and a final number formatted using D21.13, but without a space after it (as the ":" stops at the final item).

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is not valid in Fortran 77 `FORMAT` statements. Gfortran will not compile it, unless you fix the code. There is no flag that will change that AFAIK (`-fbackslash` should not help here).

If I understand the intention correctly (and I may be wrong), the backslash does the same as the dollar sign in some other compilers and prevents terminating a record (line). In that case the `advance="no"` put in the write statement should help. It is Fortran 90, but you should not avoid it just for that reason.