# Use of double back slashes in Fortran formating

Tags: fortran

I am working on an old Fortran code and the following syntax puzzled me:

```
102 FORMAT(' INPUTS ',/1H ,12('='),//
   +' HERE THE SCORE '\\ 
   +' WELL DONE')
```

I don't understand what are the backslashes doing? and like this it is not compiling, without the back slashes it is but I would like to understand and not just removing them.

Comment: The character `/` is a forward slash, not a back slash, which would be \.

Comment: sorry I miswrotte it, it was really \\

Comment: the // works fne, the \\ gives the results 'Error: Unexpected element ‘'’ in format string at (1)' pointing to the back slash

Comment: [Backslash editing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43116912/3157076) is a non-standard thing in some compilers.  Do you know which compiler was original used for this code?  (Whether backslash editing is the intention is unclear.)

Comment: @francescalus it was ifort